# Lurker mail archiver: how to make it prefer the HTML atached body to the plaintext?

Tags: email, archiving

I'm using [Lurker](http://lurker.sourceforge.net) for archiving a mailing list.

Lurker is nice because it can deal with MIME, HTML and attachments, and render these things in the archive.

Here is the irony though: when Lurker is faced with a message which has an HTML body as well as some plain-text rendering of it, it renders the plain text. The HTML is accessible via the attachment links and looks fine when you click on that to look at it. This defeats the purpose of the archiver's capabilities: why display the plain text, when you're capable of rendering HTML with all the inline images and whatnot? The plain text is for recipients using e-mail programs which can't deal with the HTML (or MIME, period). Lurker ends up HTML-izing this ugly plain text version of the message!

Does anyone know of a way to configure to Lurker prefer the "text/html" MIME part, when it is available, for rendering the content of the message, and only using the plain text version when there is no HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard-coded behavior.  A `multipart/alternative` message is treated by displaying the `text/plain` part. Another hard-coded behavior is that Lurker strips all tags from HTML for security reasons, which necessitates the former behavior. The desired behavior would require more delicate handling of HTML in Lurker.